# How to display recent views of a certain node=type per user

Tags: drupal-7, flags

For Drupal 7
I want to display a block with recent viewed nodes of a certain type. It is like booking.com where you see the last hotels you viewed.
This functionality has to work for unregistered users.
I looked to flags but can not figure out if and how this will work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a article specific for your needs. You will need few modules help and views to satisfy your needs.

http://jan.tomka.name/blog/list-recently-viewed-nodes-drupal